# How can I access the path of the selected project in Eclipse's Project Explorer using a menuContribution?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to get the path of the project selected in eclipse project explorer, I have created a menuContribution on the right click menu want to access the path in the handler.

I tried this code but was unable to import ProjectExplorer class.

```
@Override public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException { // Get the active part IPartService partService = (IPartService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IPartService.class); IPart activePart = partService.getActivePart();
// Check if the active part is a Project Explorer
if (activePart instanceof ProjectExplorer) {
    // Get the selected projects
    List<IProject> selectedProjects = ((ProjectExplorer) activePart).getSelectedProjects();

    // Get the path of the selected project
    if (selectedProjects.size() > 0) {
        IProject selectedProject = selectedProjects.get(0);
        String path = selectedProject.getFullPath().toString();

        // Do something with the path
        System.out.println(path);
    }
}

return null;
}
```

Comment: Handlers normally use `HandlerUtil.getCurrentSelection(event)` to get the current selection. Also I don't see a `getSelectedProjects` method in the current `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.ProjectExplorer`

Answer (score 0):

So i have some code to get the Project no matter what the current selection is in a view or editor - i know its not complete but should do for most - hope it helps a bit:

```
@Override
public final Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    ISelection selection = HandlerUtil.getActiveMenuSelection(event);
    IResource resource = Activator.getSelectedResource(selection);
    IProject project = resource.getProject();
    //do something

    return null;
}

public static IResource getSelectedResource(ISelection selection) {
if (selection instanceof TreeSelection) {
  Object selectedElement = ((TreeSelection) selection).getFirstElement();
  if (selectedElement instanceof IResource) {
    return (IResource) selectedElement;
  } else if (selectedElement instanceof IPackageFragmentRoot) {
    return ((IPackageFragmentRoot) selectedElement).getResource();
  } else if (selectedElement instanceof IJavaProject) {
    return ((IJavaProject) selectedElement).getProject();
  }
} else if (selection instanceof TextSelection) {
  IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
  IEditorPart editor = page.getActiveEditor();
  if (editor.getEditorInput() instanceof IFileEditorInput fei) {
    return fei.getFile();
  }
}
return null;
```

}